# Disconnected monitor is still reported as connected

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, monitors, hdmi

What I did:

1. Connect a monitor via HDMI. The output of `xrandr` is as expected:

   ```
   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
   eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
      1920x1080     60.01*+
      1400x1050     59.98  
      1600x900      60.00  
      1280x1024     60.02  
      1280x960      60.00  
      1368x768      60.00  
      1280x720      60.00  
      1024x768      60.00  
      1024x576      60.00  
      960x540       60.00  
      800x600       60.32    56.25  
      864x486       60.00  
      640x480       59.94  
      720x405       60.00  
      640x360       60.00  
   DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
      1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
      1680x1050     59.88  
      1600x900      60.00  
      1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
      1440x900      59.90  
      1280x800      59.91  
      1152x864      75.00  
      1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
      1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
      832x624       74.55  
      800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
      720x576       50.00  
      720x480       60.00    59.94  
      640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
      720x400       70.08  
   VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```

   The file `/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-2/status`, which corresponds to the connected monitor, contains the word `connected` (as expected).
2. Then I disconnect the HDMI cable. When I check `/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-2/status` it still contains `connected`.
3. When I now run `xrandr` again it somehow resets my setup and the file is updated to reflect the correct status, namely `disconnected`.

**My question:** How can I fix the behavior, so that the /sys file system reflects the status correctly as soon as the cable is unplugged? And I do not have to call `xrandr` to initiate the update.

Alternative question: What is `xrandr` doing, that causes the update of the /sys filesystem? This way I could maybe write a little script that periodically causes the update.

During this I also had a look at `udevadm monitor`:

```
    monitor will print the received events for:
    UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
    KERNEL - the kernel uevent

    KERNEL[7260.824844] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
    UDEV  [7260.825690] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
    KERNEL[7280.130646] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
    UDEV  [7280.138375] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
```

The first two lines appeared right after plugging the HDMI cable into the computer, however the last two lines only appeared when I ran the `xrandr` command mentioned in step 3.

If it is any help here is my kernel version:

```
Linux archy 4.8.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 9 07:24:34 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does it do the same thing when you turn off your monitor instead of unplugging it?

Comment: No, when turning the monitor off and still having the HDMI cable plugged in, the status remains `connected`, even so after running `xrandr`.